# Excel Macro to find and match item quantity between 2 sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need an help to construct a code, Which needs to compare two sheet's data. Both sheets has common header. each has 3 types of data: Product, Serial and Qty

- Sheet 1 is master record
- Sheet 2 is qry record

i am able to compare each column but i need match data value.

for instances:

if sheet 1 has this "P56017-A" product in a column, and column B has its Serial number and column C has its Quantity.

i need to find the same product in sheet 2 and get its quantity and compare with sheet 1.

- in sheet 1 this same product has 50 qty.
- in sheet 2 this same product has 40 only means requirement does not meets so its a mismatch.
- so this Mismatch product number and quantity should be pasted in Sheet 3.

I am not so familiar with VBA and Macro but if this can be done i can reduce some works for my brother to sinf mismatch instead of manual findings

Macro code:

```
Sub Mismatch()

    Set ws1 = sheetS("S1")
    Set ws2 = sheetS("S2")

    ws1UniqueIDCol = "A"
    ws1LineIdCol = "C"
    ws1ValToWriteCol = "D"
    ws1StartRow = 1
    ws1EndRow = ws1.UsedRange.Rows(ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row
    
    
    ws2UniqueIDCol = "A"
    ws2LineIdCol = "C"
    ws2ValToCopyCol = "D"
    ws2EndRow = ws2.UsedRange.Rows(ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row
    
    For i = ws1StartRow To ws1EndRow        '
        searchKey = ws1.Range(ws1UniqueIDCol & i) & ws1.Range(ws1LineIdCol & i)
        If (searchKey <> "") Then
            For j = ws2StartRow To ws2EndRow
                 foundKey = ws2.Range(ws2UniqueIDCol & j) & ws2.Range(ws2LineIdCol & j)
                 If (searchKey = foundKey) Then
                    ws1.Range(ws1ValToWriteCol & i).Value2 = ws2.Range(ws2ValToCopyCol & j).Value2
                    Exit For
                 End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Sheet 1

[image]

Sheet 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sub Mismatch()

```
Set ws1 = Sheets("S1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("S2")

ws1UniqueIDCol = "A"
ws1LineIdCol = "C"
ws1ValToWriteCol = "D"
ws1StartRow = 1
ws1EndRow = ws1.UsedRange.Rows(ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

ws2StartRow = 1
ws2EndRow = ws2.UsedRange.Rows(ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

ws2UniqueIDCol = "A"
ws2LineIdCol = "C"
ws2ValToCopyCol = "D"
ws2EndRow = ws2.UsedRange.Rows(ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

For i = ws1StartRow To ws1EndRow        '
    
    searchKey = ws1.Range(ws1UniqueIDCol & i) & ws1.Range(ws1LineIdCol & i)
    
    If (searchKey <> "") Then
        For j = ws2StartRow To ws2EndRow
             foundKey = ws2.Range(ws2UniqueIDCol & j) & ws2.Range(ws2LineIdCol & j)
             
             If (searchKey = foundKey) Then
                ws1.Range(ws1ValToWriteCol & i).Value = "match"
         Else
             If ws2.Range(ws2UniqueIDCol & j) = ws1.Range(ws1UniqueIDCol & i) Then
             If ws1.Range(ws1LineIdCol & i) <> ws2.Range(ws2LineIdCol & j) Then
                        ws1.Range(ws1ValToWriteCol & i).Value = ws2.Range(ws2LineIdCol & j).Value
```

End If
End If

End If
Next j
End If
Next i
End Sub

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).